# How to create a random, warped 2D grid?

Tags: algorithm, random, grid

How do you create a random grid where the lines aren't orthogonal (and cells aren't a perfect square), but are warped?

Here's an example of what I mean:
[image: Warped Grid]

(Credit: screenshot taken from a video by Silvarret about the game Townscaper.)

Lines curve. Sometimes many cells come together in a single point. Yet, it still looks like a grid and the cells are clearly visible and roughly equal in size and shape.

I have absolutely no clue how to go about something like this. How is this achieved? Is there an algorithm for this? How would you detect the cell over which the mouse hovers?

Comment: [Oskar Stålberg has shown and explained the algorithm in his tweets](https://twitter.com/OskSta/status/1147881669350891521) - have you run into any trouble applying this to your case?

Comment: Oh my, how did I miss that! Yes, that explains everything for me, thanks a lot! (I've been searching for terms like "warped grid", never finding anything, but apparantly the magic word was "quadrangulations".) Now I don't know what to do with this question - should I keep it online?

Comment: You could write a step-by-step breakdown of the algorithm as you understand it and post it as an Answer below.